# Android XML table layout for small and xlarge screens

Tags: android, xml, android-tablelayout, screen-size

I have a XML layout written for 3.2 inch screen test phone. When I try this on larger screens, I would like the Table to expand accordingly and fill the screen. I tried changing a lot of match_parents/fill_parents/weights, but couldn't fit properly. Can anyone help me on this by trying this code on a larger screen, say Nexus 10 tablet screen size?
My XML code is as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Hit Me" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_vipra"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#d65906" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_table_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#fcc480"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="1dip"
                android:text="Table Header Title" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_table_header2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#fcc480"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="1dip"
                android:text="">

            </TextView>
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#d65906" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView0a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="*" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="First Name" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="Middle Name" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView03"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="Last Name" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#d65906" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="1" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#d65906" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="2" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView23"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#d65906" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="3" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView31"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView32"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView33"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#d65906" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="4" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView41"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView42"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView43"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#d65906" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="5" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView51"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView52"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView53"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#d65906" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="6" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView61"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView62"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView63"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#d65906" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="7" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView71"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView72"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView73"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:background="#d65906" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="!" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView81"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView82"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView83"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fcc480"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:text="" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What did you mean `couldn't fit properly`? Have you tried to define XML for each screen size? [Start here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: What I meant is the table doesn't fill the full height of screen. The table fits full in width. But the height seems to be wrapped and not filling height.

Comment: Ok. I could resolve the table width content. Thanks for the help! I will post the answer tomorrow.

Comment: Here are two links which helped me write the code. [http://android.amberfog.com/?p=328](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=328)  and [http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/](http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/)  Hope this helps.